# getChildren() Position in Magento

Tags: magento

I have this code that displays a hover effect and displays sub menus however they will not sort as displayed in the admin. I tried using getChildrenCategories() however this doesn't return the data. Please help.

```
<?php
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

$_currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();



if(!Mage::registry('current_product')) {
  if ( count( $_categories ) > 0 ) {
    ?>

    <nav class="site_nav sub" id="shop_sub_nav">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ( $_categories as $_category ): ?>
                <li class="menu-item-has-children <?= ( $active === 'shop' ) ? 'current-menu-item' : ''; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl( $_category ) ?>">
                        <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="cat_hover_nav sub-menu" style="width: 190px;">
                        <?php
                        $loadCategory  = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $_category->getId() );
                        $subCategories = explode( ',', $loadCategory->getChildren() );
                        ?>


                        <?php
                        if ( count( $subCategories ) > 0 ) {
                            echo '<ul>';
                            foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId ) {
                                $cat = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/category' )->load( $subCategoryId );

                                echo '<li class="' . ( ( $this->isCategoryActive( $cat ) ) ? 'current-menu-item' : '' ) . '"><a href="' . $cat->getURL() . '">' . $cat->getName() . '</a></li>';
                            }
                            echo '</ul>';
                        }

                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <?php
}

}
```